# Why does C# Program Run Slower without Debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I have a short program to print out all Armstrong Numbers from 10 to 999,999.

When I run in debug mode it finishes in under 1 second.

When I run without debugging, two command windows are opened.  When the second one finally closes, the output is displayed on the first one (this takes about 12 seconds).  However, if I kill the second window from the task manager; the complete output is displayed in the first window.

Also, running the straight .exe files results in the same behavior as running without debugging.

Additionally:  When I run the straight exe file I am getting around 100 MB of RAM usage (which as far as I know I shouldn't be for a program this small).

Here's my code:

```cs
using System;
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ARMSTRONG NUMBERS FOUND FROM 10 THROUGH 999999\n");
        int total_armstrong = 0;
        for (int i = 10; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            int temp = i;
            int k;
            int total = 0;

            for (k = 0; temp != 0; k++) //runs only 6 times maximum    gives me the exponent to use below
                temp /= 10;
            temp = i;
            while (temp != 0) //runs only 6 times maximum
            {
                total += (int)Math.Pow(temp % 10, k);  //calculates the value of each digit raised to the exponent calculated above
                temp /= 10;
            }
            if (total == i)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(total);
                total_armstrong++;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\nTOTAL NUMBER OF ARMSTRONG NUMBERS FOUND WAS " + total_armstrong);
    }
}
```

Image of what it looks like while running:
Output appears in left window after right closes

[image: image in question]

[image]

Comment: Nothing in your code would cause two command windows to show up. How are you launching your program? Also double check that your project type is a "Console Application" not a "Windowed Application"

Comment: Two command windows open when I either do ctrl+f5 from inside VS 2013 (which should run it w/o debugging)   OR when I open the debug/release exe that is generated by VS2013

Comment: Is this the only project in your solution?

Comment: Yes,  in fact this is the only project I currently have in Visual Studio at all  (I just started with C#)

Comment: Just tested your code and it works as expected (1 console window only). What happens when you create a new project  - console application and copy-paste this code into Program.cs?

Comment: Can we see the Solution Explorer window within your Visual Studio window? How did you start this project in Visual Studio? Is this a Console Application (like Scott asked)? Try choosing "File", "New Project", be sure to make a new Console Application, copy-paste the above code into the new project.

Comment: When I make a new project the behavior is the same  (also, I edited to include my Solution Explorer window)

Comment: There is something wrong with your development environment. It could be Windows or Visual Studio. Apparently a command prompt is executed when you execute a .NET console application and from you description it seems that this command prompt is the parent process of the console application. Reinstall Visual Studio and/or Windows is my best advice or if that is too much you will have to focus your troubleshooting on what triggers this behavior. It is certainly not the C# code you have written that is the source of your problem.

Comment: Well, thanks for your help.  I've been meaning to do a fresh Windows install sometime  guess that's what will have to fix it  :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up re-installing Visual Studio/Windows and the problem resolved itself. In the end the nuclear option always solves the problem.